# How to create a custom lambda base image for dotnet 6

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda

I want to create a custom lambda base image based on dotnet 6. But I cannot find a complete guide to do so, I have tried searching AWS docs, but they ended up making me even more confused. There are many python and npm based solutions, but I could not find anything specific to dotnet.
I want to install Runtime Interface Client in a SDK 6 docker image, so that I can make it work with a lambda.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what customization you are doing, but [the guide for using containers for a .NET image](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/csharp-image.html) on Lambda does give you several options for starting out.

Once you have your image customized from the base image, you can upload it to your Amazon ECR container registry as instructed in that guide.